# Refactored function names in PyCharm don't apply to notebook

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

Refactoring function names in a module in PyCharm generally, I think, will refactor any use of that function name with the scope of a project.  I noticed, however, that functions in my notebook, which is in the project, were not refactored.  Is there a way to include the notebook when refactoring?

I have noticed that the jupyter notebook does not seem to be very integrated into PyCharm.  Maybe this functionality hasn't been added.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have refactoring that covers also notebooks, in the dialog window for editing change of function name ensure that you have `Search for_text occurrences` option marked. In the refactoring preview, function occurrences in notebooks can be found in the section "non-code files".